# Export excel to sql through Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, excel, export

I am trying to export some Excel data to SQl tables using Asp.net. I have downloaded and installed the database connectiviy engine and everything working fine on my local machine.

But I am facing problem while trying on server. It is giving error 
 The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

I checked the server and Office is not installed on server. Will it affect export if Office not available on server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MS Office Compatibility issue. After installing the MS Office go through the below link will helpful.
[CompatibleIssueResolve](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-the-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine?forum=vstsdb)

Comment: This means Office installation on server is must for using Access Database Engine. Also we have 2 servers application and database, on which server I have to install Office and Access database engine

Comment: Yes, I think both the machines must have MS Office.